# Accepting changes in LaTeX using the trackchanges package using Python

Tags: thesis, python, trackchanges

Does anyone have experience using the `trackchanges` package with `python3` to accept the changes when editing a document?  I am able to view all changes from various editors, I just am not sure how to accept those changes.  Here is the reference:  https://sourceforge.net/projects/trackchanges/.  The python script that was used was written in python2.  I have been unsuccessful in getting python2 to work with the file.  I can't install the standard modules as I keep getting error messaages.

```
# import standard Python 2.4 modules
from optparse import OptionParser 
from copy import deepcopy
import sys
import tempfile
import readline
import os
import re
```

Here is the error message I am getting:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>python2 -m pip install optparse
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Collecting optparse
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement optparse (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for optparse
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 20.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

This is true for each of the modules I am trying to install.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I suspect this is a pure python question (even if your target is tex files) and isn't clearly on topic here, python2-python3 upgrade questions would be better on stackoverflow (I assume you should be upgrading the script tp python3 rather than trying to get pythin2 modules installed)

Comment: Your errors are not related to LaTeX. Anyway, as the comment before the imports in the Python module says, all the referenced modules are already part of the Python (2) standard library, so no need to install them. Nevertheless you probably have to install PyQt4, which seems to be another dependency.

Comment: The tool is a bit outdated, not just because it was written for Python 2 but also because it uses the Qt4 framework for the graphical user interface, whereas Qt5 has been released in 2012. It will be difficult to get it to work properly (as you have noticed) and in the future it may get worse when libraries get further updates. So it would be best if the tool gets updated, by the original author or possibly as a forked version by someone else - in the mean time I'm not sure there is much you can do to solve the issues.